# How to go to next scene if a number equals zero

Tags: actionscript-3, scene

I'm creating game where when an object rolls over another object the object disappears and when it does 1 is taken from a thing on the stage that counts how many objects are left; however, I want it so that when it equals zero it goes to a new scene. This is my code so far:

```
var nObjects:Number = 5;

An.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision4)    

function handleCollision4( e:Event ):void
{
if(An.hitTestObject(Octo)){
An.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStopDrag4);

function onStopDrag4(e:MouseEvent):void {
e.target.StopDrag;
if(An.hitTestObject(Octo)){



   removeChild(MovieClip(Octo));
    nObjects--;
    trace(nObjects)
    myText.text = String(nObjects);


}
}
  //there are five of these when they are all deleted nObjects does equal zero

 if (nObjects==0);

{
gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 3");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to close your `handleCollision4` and its `if` statement.  To help keep that clear (where encapsulation occurs) remember to always properly indent your code as it will make it easier for others (and you) to read it and spot syntax errors.
- In `onStopDrag4`, you have what looks like a function call to `StopDrag`.  Don't forget your parenthesis.
- Your test for `if (nObjects == 0) {` is outside your `onStopDrag4` listener, meaning it only runs once during the initial document read; you want it inside the listener so it gets run after each `nObject` decrement.  Also, do not add semicolons after a condition.

Properly formatted, it should look like this:

```
var nObjects:Number = 5;
An.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision4)    

function handleCollision4(e:Event):void {
    if (An.hitTestObject(Octo)) {
        An.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStopDrag4);
    }
}

function onStopDrag4(e:MouseEvent):void {
    e.target.StopDrag();
    if (An.hitTestObject(Octo)) {
        removeChild(MovieClip(Octo));
        nObjects--;
        trace(nObjects)
        myText.text = String(nObjects);
    }

    //there are five of these when they are all deleted nObjects does equal zero
    if (nObjects == 0) {
        gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 3");
    }
}
```

Comment: But how would i create that listener? (sorry about my noobiness but i only started actionscript recently)

Comment: A listener is a function that has been registered for an event.  Ergo, when you write `someObject.addEventListener(eventName, fooFunction)`, `fooFunction` is your listener and has been registered for your event (pretty straightforward).

Comment: But I get the error: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type Number.

Comment: You cannot register `Number` to a listener since events are not generated from them, and (as a class) `Number` does not have a method called `addEventListener`.  If you want to register `Event.ENTER_FRAME`, that's a Stage event, so you need to register it on the stage as follows: `this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision4)`.  Of course, you can write it other ways since `this` is just a local pointer to current namespace; substituting it with `Stage` or `root` are also valid.  I have no idea what object `An` was that you were using since you never declared it in your sample.